# Using the startsWith function to recognize the first three digits if zip code

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, startswith

I am attempting to use the `startsWith` function to recognize the first three digits of the zip code being entered. The zip code that I am testing is 44646. When I add this it should be recognized as `446` is one of the fields in the `str` array. The else statement is being recognized and is reading though.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```js
$('#salesforce_submit').change(function () {
  zipVal = $('#zip').val();
  var zipVals = [ 44030 , 44048 , 44082 , 44003 , 44093 , 44076 , 44062 , 44021 , 44046 , 44099 , 44032 , 44047 , 44010 , 44057 , 44086 , 44064 , 44024 , 44023 , 44065 , 44022 , 44072 , 44040 , 44143 , 44094 , 44139 , 44146 , 44128 , 44105 , 44122 , 44124 , 44121 , 44117 , 44108 , 44110 , 44103 , 44106 , 44118 , 44120 , 44104 , 44114 , 44127 , 44125 , 44131 , 44134 , 44129 , 44130 , 44144 , 44109 , 44115 , 44136 , 44133 , 44147 , 44141 , 44067 , 44056 , 44087 , 44195 ];
  var str = [ 442 , 443 , 444 , 445 , 446 , 447 , 437 , 438 , 439 , 457 , 434 , 435 , 436 , 164 , 165 , 163 , 161 , 160 , 162 , 150 , 151 , 152 , 156 , 153 , 154 , 585 , 716 , 142 ];
  if ( zipVal.startsWith( +str ) ) {
   contains = 'Contain in place';
      $('#show').text(contains);
  } else {
   contains = 'Contain not in place';
      $('#show').text(contains);
  }
  console.log(contains);
  if ( zipVals.includes( +zipVal ) ) {
   zipAssign = 'AB';
  } else {
   zipAssign = '';
  }
  console.log(zipAssign);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="salesforce_submit">
<div><input id="zip" placeholder="Zip/Postal Code*" class="input block" maxlength="6" name="zip" type="text" pattern= "[0-9]{5}"></div>
<p id="show"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+str` expressions give you a NaN since you transform array to number. So, try to check this way:

`if (str.find(num => zipVal.startsWith(num)) !== undefined;) ...`

And the same should be done for `if ( zipVals.includes( +zipVal ) ) {`